# How to fix 'Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names' error in Symfony when one object is brought in lowercase?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

First symfony project, i try to make a imdb like site . when i go from one page (season_show) to another (episode_show)by a link instanciating objects in the parm converter route, one of my object is brought in lowercase creating a "Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: "App\Entity\program" vs "App\Entity\Program"." error.
i already tried setting all lowercase occurences of "program" in my project to Program but it didnt work. Has someone any clue on how to correct it ?

```
<?php
// src/Controller/ProgramController.php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Repository\ProgramRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Program;
use App\Entity\Season;
use App\Entity\Episode;

#[Route('/program', name: 'program_')]
Class ProgramController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('{programId}/seasons/{seasonId}', name: 'season_show')]
    public function showSeason(Season $season, Program $Program,Episode $episode): Response
    {
        $episodes  = $season->getEpisodes();
                
        return $this->render('program/season_show.html.twig', [
            'Program' => $Program,
            'season' => $season,
            'episodes' => $episodes
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('{program}/seasons/{season}/episode/{episode}', name: 'episode_show')]

    public function showEpisode (Program $Program,Season $season, Episode $episode): Response{
       
       
        return $this->render('program/episode_show.html.twig',[
            'Program' => $Program,
            'season' => $season,
            'episode' => $episode
        ]);
    }
}
```

season_show.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Série {{ program.title }}, saison {{ season.number }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="media">
        <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="{{ program.poster }}" alt="{{ program.title }} poster">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h1 class="mt-0">{{ program.title }} saison {{ season.number }}</h1>
            <p>{{ program.synopsis }}</p>
            <p>Catégorie : {{ program.Category.name }}</p>
            <p>Saison : {{ season.number }}</p>
            <p>{{ episode.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ episode.synopsis }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <a href="{{ path('program_index') }}">
        Retour à la liste des programmes
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post code of `App\Entity\Program`, check the class name, it must be Program (with capital P)

Comment: Seems the Route is wrong - it should be `{programId}` not `{program}` for `episode_show `

Comment: Is your (physical) entity file actually called `Program.php` and not `program.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty - and without to know your entity File:

The error: `Case mismatch between loaded and declared class name` is thrown because either your entity filename is in lowercase - `program.php` and your classname is `Program` or your filename is correct `Program.php` and your classname is in lowercase.

Please take a look to [Symfony Coding Standards (Naming Conventions)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions) to read more about symfony's naming strategys. This makes it easier for you in the future to debug and read your application codes.

By the way, the query parameters in your route are incorrect your function should looks like this:

```
#[Route('{programId}/seasons/{seasonId}', name: 'season_show')]
public function showSeason($programId = null, $seasonId = null): Response
{
    //your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be sometime a bug in the typing of the relations. If someone has this problem again, check with your entities if the manyToMany or manyToOne relations aren't typing in lowercase.